# how access my database mysql from another computer

Tags: python, tkinter, treeview, mysql-python

I have a program made in python that is responsible for making the CRUD of a mysql database. On my machine it works perfectly, however when I try to pass it to another machine it doesn't work. I believe it's because it's not hosted on a server and I have no idea how to do it either. How do I put it on a server on the internet and access it?
Thank you very much in advance. Below is the python code responsible for connecting to the database.

```py
 import mysql.connector


class DBHelper:
    def __init__(self):
        '''
        O construtor é responsável por fazer a conexão com o banco de dados e criar as tabelas
        livros, autores e editoras.
        '''
        self.data_base = mysql.connector.connect(
            host='localhost',
            user='root',
            passwd='',
            database='livraria_db'
        )

        self.cursor = self.data_base.cursor()

        self.cursor.execute('''
        CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS livros (
            id INT (255) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
            titulo VARCHAR (255) NOT NULL,
            autor VARCHAR (255) NOT NULL,
            editora VARCHAR (255) NOT NULL,
            paginas INT (255) NOT NULL,
            proprietario VARCHAR (255) NOT NULL 
        );
        ''')

        self.cursor.execute('''
        CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS autores (
            id INT (255) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
            autor VARCHAR (255) NOT NULL
        );
        ''')

        self.cursor.execute('''
        CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS editoras (
            id INT (255) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
            editora VARCHAR (255) NOT NULL
        );
        ''')
```

Comment: You can access the mysql installed on your computer by learning its real ip address. If you are not connected to a VPN, you can find out the IP address via http://icanhazip.com/. And you can write the ip address where it says localhost in your code. But I don't recommend it, I just gave this information because it's possible. If you are going to make your application accessible to other users, it must be hosted on a server, for example, you can create it here https://aws.amazon.com/tr/rds/mysql/ this is just an option. There are many providers like this, it's your choice.

Comment: @gizemsever i tried the heroku but it gives me errors, can you tell me if aws is free?

Comment: no it's not free

Answer (score 0):

You should have the IP of your computer that the Access point can see, and replace the with the
`host = 'internal IP'`
I think you should also have `port = 3306`

you can access the database from any machine that connected to the same network. If you want to access it remotely, install a client VPN like wireguard and connect from anywhere

Comment: but if my computer is off the the user won't be able to access it, ok?

Comment: yes, The machine that has the database must be online 24 hours so users can query the database